# how to find ServiceName in Azure Cloud billing export

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-billing-api

In Azure Cost analysis console, we have the option to filter by Service Name. The same Column is NOT there in the billing CSV export I’m getting from Azure. Does anyone know how to filter Service name in billing export

Comment: What view are you using? Service name is only included when you are grouping data by service name, service tier, or meter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to see cost analysis in 'Cost Management + Billing | Billing account' menu, and I also found the downloaded CSV files don't contain an Service Name column. So I prefer to use cost management api to get the details.
Here's the api link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage

By the way, I remembered that if someone wanna use this api, please make sure that the target subscription has joined Azure plan.

Hope it will do some help. Wish you a good day.